# Google Maps API : how to move an existing circle, and recenter the map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i just can't find a solution for this, so ... let's try here! :-)

with google maps API V3, i drew a circle this way :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $d['location_lat'] . ', ' . $d['location_lon']; ?>);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: map_center,
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 12
    });

    var area_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      center: map_center,
      strokeWeight: 0,
      fillColor: '#ec519b',
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      map: map,
      radius: 1200
    });
});
```

in a div like this :
`<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>`

the code works so far, no problem here.

what i would like to do is :
- the user type his location in a text field (exemple : "London")
- i get the coordinates (lat, lon) with google maps geocode via an ajax script
- i want to move the circle on these new coordinates (lat, lon) and re center the map on the circle (= same coordinates)

i'm ok with the step of getting the new coordinates of the city, i write both the latitude and longitude in two hidden inputs for being recorded later when the user validate the form, so i can also reuse it with javascript/jquery :

```
var new_lat = $("#js_lat").val();
var new_lon = $("#js_lon").val();
```

is anyone have a clue of how to do this?
i tried so many things, but i just can't make it working :/

thanks by advance, let me know if you need any further informations.

have a great week end! :-)

Comment: [example circle at geocoded address](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_changeCircleRadius.html)

Comment: wow, that was quick and efficient! i have to simplify this script, but the solution is 100% there!
thanks a lot for you help, you totally answered my question! :-)